# WCF Service converts localhost to www.localhost.com only in case of json response

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I Have created simple wcf service which have 3 methods. Each ov these methods works in case of single [WebGet] Attribute, but if i add (ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json), its converting localhost to www.localhost.com address.

Here's my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <services>
      <service name="PromoCenyParseService.PromoCenyParseService">
      <endpoint kind="webHttpEndpoint"
       contract="PromoCenyParseService.IPromoCenyParseService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And here's Service Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPromoCenyParseService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Product ParseItem(string url);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<Product> ParsePage(string urlPage);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    int GetNumOfPages(string urlPage);
}
```

Could you please tell my what am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

endpoint added, no results. Still working on xml, not working on json

**Update 2:**

I have discovered that problem exists only for functions:

```
ParseItem
```

and

```
ParsePage
```

This function returns normal value.

I have tried with various endpoint configurations etc.

Where is the problem?

**Update 3:**

I have discovered, that it happens only when function returns object that is DataContract.

Comment: don't you need to define an endpoint in your config? There you could set the hostname to localhost

Comment: I have discovered, that it happens only when function returns object that is DataContract. Any resolution for now?

Comment: Have you really added the address and the baseaddress attributes of the endpoint tag? Your code above doesn't reflect this. Have you anywhere in your code or configuration used the string 'localhost'? If yes please show it in your question.

Comment: I have even copied-pasted your cofiguration. It just broke everything :P For now, i have a fully working xml response service based on webHttpBinding. Problem about localhost and still exist. Is it possible to make Json response on webHttpBinding?

Comment: Yes, i did that. altough i used restful behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found issue.

Problem exists in DateTime object which exists in my DataContract. I supose there is different Time Zone or different default date format onmy server.

Resolution of this problem:

```
[DataMember]
public DateTime DiscountStart
{
    get { return this._discountStart.ToUniversalTime(); }
    set { this._discountStart = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
   <!-- <protocolMapping> I think you don't need this
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping> -->
    <services>
      <service name="PromoCenyParseService.PromoCenyParseService">
      <endpoint address="localohost"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                contract="PromoCenyParseService.IPromoCenyParseService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

If this still doesn't work, open your browser and go to `"http://localhost?wsdl`" and post the result here.

Comment: This one still redirects to www.localhost.com, but strange thing is, that its redirecting only in case of Json response.

Any another solution?